# Enterprise Architect Pure Virtual Functions "=0"

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

I'm having trouble implementing a pure virtual C++ Function in an UML Diagram in Enterprise Architect.

I created a class who has a pure virtual function called "act()" the flags for virtual is set true and the modifiers are set on pure but still in the diagram the function lacks the "=0".

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pure virtual (abstract) functions are rendered in italics in UML, there shpuödn't be a `= 0` shown in the diagrams.

Comment: but how would you distinguish between just a virtual and a pure virtual?

Comment: Why should it matter if a function is *just* virtual? If you follow the LSP it's immaterial.

Comment: because pure virtual is like abstract in java and virtual is just for polymorphism (if I remember well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property isAbstract of an operation is defined as:
isAbstract : Boolean [1..1] If true, then the BehavioralFeature does not have an implementation, and one must be supplied by a more specific Classifier.

The notion of pure "abstract" is not defined in the norm, it could be seen as a language question not an UML one.

In EA, for an abstract operation, you get the Modifier Pure, but I did not find his definition in the specification.

And the graphical representation does not change see:

[image]

A solution could be to define a stereotype (easy and fast in EA) :
[image]

But done like that, this is just a "tip", to define a stereotype on Operation, you would create a profile with the stereotype, then imort the profile in your EA project ... Another story.